# Interpretation of 'I will help you with a boat'

Tags: grammar, meaning

I want to know how to interpret a sentence "I will help you with a boat".
I know that there is an expression 'help sb with N' where N refers to something that sb needs help on/with.

However, because there is an 'a' before the word 'boat' it feels weird to understand it that way.

What is the correct way to understand the sentence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the context? Is the speaker offering to provide a boat for a journey that someone has to make?

Comment: @KateBunting There was no context available. It's from a short answer question from my friend's book. I agree with our interpretation but my friends are telling me that 'help sb with A' should not be interpreted as providing means to sb.

Comment: If the speaker was offering to help someone who already had a boat, I would expect them to say "I will help you with _the_ boat".

Comment: @KateBunting Right. But is it okay to interpret the sentence as *providing* a boat to the person who cannot cross the river?

Comment: That is how I interpreted the sentence in my original comment.

Comment: So I guess it is okay to interpret it that way. Thanks Kate.